# laravel-permission Is there a binding relationship between permissions and routes when the user middleware determines permissions?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

For example, in the following figure: permission:member_info|member_add is added to the member routing group. If a user has one of these two permissions, the entire member routing can be accessed. Do we have to write them down on specific routes one by one? That's a lot. It doesn't feel that way. If it is not written in the specific route, how should this permission and route be bound?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FapF6.png)

I don't know what to do at the moment, but I feel that it is unscientific to write on the route one by one.

Like the previous comparison url, the permission is the url, which is checked from the data table and compared with the current request url

Comment: Did you test if adding the permissions to the middleware of the route group was enough for the underlying routes? I suspect that all routes in a group have the defined middleware setting applied.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.